# Realm - insert object into specific location

Tags: android, realm

I was wondering if there's any way to manage RealmResults just as List<>. Is there a simple way to achieve adding at specific index functionality through transactions? What I mean is that I want to take item from one position and put it in other position in the database, preferably without using sort which requires specific field in object to sort by it. I want position to be reflected as an index at which item is positioned.

To summarize, how to do this -> realmResults.add(INDEX, object); Using realm transactions?
Also on inserts I need to put objects into first index in the database.

Comment: Why would you want that?

Comment: I wanted to directly use RealmResults as data provider in my RecyclerView.Adapter. I'm building grid view with drag and drop functionality, therefore I need simple way to reorganize my objects and save positions. But doing it manually in custom field in object is a nightmare, why can't it just behave like list with normal indexes. I tried with SQLite and cursor but it was even worse with many classes to handle that.

Comment: *doing it manually in custom field in object is a nightmare* Why? Actually sounds like a good idea, since then it will also be persisted. If you just change some indexes in a list, next time you start the app the indexes will be different again

Comment: Well, I guess it would need crazy amounts of checks for positions, and if I do it like that every position tweak would trigger data set change because RealmResults are listening for changes, so for 100 objects in the grid when I want to move something from the bottom to the top RecyclerView would reload whole grid everytime for each item changed. So I'd have to build some mechanism to restrain that. All of that sounds like a lot of work and extra code, I don't know, maybe it's the only way

Comment: I've done it with position field, it actually was way easier than I thought it would be, and it works with swaping items, adding new items to the beginning, reordering however I want. I'm going to post solution to this later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We [talked about this on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/58ggl9/questions_thread_october_20_2016/d91jvfo/?context=1000), and the solution is to explicitly add a field `position`, and use `findAllSorted(MyObjFields.POSITION)`, which automatically updates whenever a new element is added.

To actually reorder the data-set in an adapter, for smaller datasets, I'd recommend creating an unmanaged copy of the result list, re-order it, and then save it back on a background thread.

```
List<Obj> unmanagedList = realm.copyFromRealm(results);


//...


realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
    public void execute(Realm realm) {
        for(int i = 0; i < unmanagedList.size(); i++) {
            Obj obj = unmanagedList.get(i);
            Obj managedObj = realm.where(Obj.class).equalTo(ObjFields.ID, obj.getId()).findFirst();
            if(managedObj != null) {
                managedObj.setPosition(i);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

---

The only edge case is that the unmanaged list doesn't auto-update if new elements are added. If you do need to handle this explicitly, then a `RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<Obj>>` can be used for a result set stored as a field variable.

Comment: I'm still new in Realm and I am wondering, so I should add the object into the `unmanagedList` first like `unmanagedList.add(0, newObj);`? But unmanagedList doesn't directly entered into Realm is it? I should `copyToRealmOrUpdate`? My confusion is at that `realm.where`. wouldn't it be `null` if there's no object with the same ID found as the list had just been inserted with the new object but no `copyToRealm` yet? Or actually I am wrong about unmanagedList?

Comment: @KevinMurvie the point is that he'd create an unmanaged copy of the result set, use that as the backing data source so that he can modify the position inside them, and when there is a change, he writes it into the Realm on a background thread, and the RealmChangeListener will be called and he can update his backing data with a new modifiable unmanaged copy.

Comment: Oh! So it can be managed just like that? I've been using that method too (using unmanaged copy to alter the contents then `copyOrUpdate`) but I haven't tried index based operation as I thought it's not needed yet but I need it now, thanks will try it soon